# Two ways of assigning a pointer. Is there a difference?

Tags: contract-development, memory

Here's one way to assign a pointer to variable z:

```
function f(uint8[] memoryArray){
    var z = memoryArray;
}
```

and here's another

```
function f(uint8[] memoryArray){
    uint8[] memory z = memoryArray;
}
```

I've tried to pass these variables to other functions and I didn't notice any difference in how they behave. Is there any difference between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the difference is pretty obvious...when you use `var` you don't declare the type and the  compiler deduces the type from the value assigned. This is considered dangerous and the solidity docs show a good example:

> The type is only deduced from the first assignment, so the loop in the following snippet is infinite, as i will have the type uint8 and any value of this type is smaller than 2000. for (var i = 0; i < 2000; i++) { ... }

Also in solidity we don't really have pointers, we have references.

Comment: also if you notice the compiler not only deduces the type of the variable but also if it needs to be in memory or in storage...that's why in the second example you also have to specify memory, since by default local variables are in storage and function parameters are in memory

Comment: Do we have references for structs?